# Song research with Echo Nest Api

Tags: java, api, mp3, echo

I'm using the Echo Nest API to obtain playlist based on similarity. In particular I'm using jEN that is an open source Java client library for the API.

I was wondering if with this functions I could get also the url of the related mp3. If not, do exist other apis that permits to obtain the audio of a song?

I'm referring to the jEN library [here](http://developer.echonest.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

This answer may reach you quite late, but I hope it helps. The Echo Nest API doesn't provide any access to the original audio file. Either the audio comes from your own audio (that you've uploaded and analyzed via the track/upload methods), or comes from our crawling of the web and other sources, and have neither the rights nor in many cases the audio itself to return.

If you are restricting your queries to, for instance, the 7digital API, then The Echo Nest API can return a track ID and URL, but you would then need to use a 7digital key to access the audio file.